# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android.graphics.Text.setPaint

Tags: android

I'm getting this wild exception from Android market report. It happens about 4-6 times a week(we have over 100k user base). I attached the code snippet under the stack. I couldn't even find the Text.java source code.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: result:3
at android.graphics.Text.setPaint(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Text.setPaint(Text.java:211)
at android.text.Layout.each(Layout.java:350)
at android.text.Layout.decorateText(Layout.java:312)
at android.text.Layout.reflow(Layout.java:410)
at android.text.Layout.reflowFull(Layout.java:369)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:114)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:67)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:51)
at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5315)
at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5765)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2781)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2649)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2624)
at com.soakmein.MessageListView$StreamAdapter.getView(MessageListView.java:1042)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1498)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1749)
at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:704)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:650)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3521)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2339)
at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3447)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3952)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:995)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1711)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1145)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
```

this is the line where the excpetion was fired:

```
messageText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: This is not near enough info to help with your problem.

Comment: @Recursed doesn't it look like the problem is in the android library rather than in the code, based on the stack trace?

Comment: To me it seems like the text is coming in differently than expected sometimes, and there is no way to tell how to fix it without seeing what gets fed into that method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post the source code.

Other than that, I would suggest you go through the stack until you find the line where the out of bounds error occurs.

It is likely that you are using a variable to keep track of the index of the array and that variable is not bounded by a rule with the same bounds as your array.